# Submit button fires twice

Tags: javascript, jquery, submit

I have the following submit:

```
 <input type="submit"  id="buttonNext" name="buttoncrd"  value="Prosegui" class="buttonNavProsegui block-ui"/>
```

When you are on the page, i want to active the submit with the keyboard button "Entry" so i made this simple  js code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(document).keypress(function(event){
       if (event.which == 13){
           $("#buttonNext").click();
        }
    });
});
```

It works correctly but i met some problem when i have the focus on the submit AND i press Enter on the keyboard. I fear that the submit fires twice, can you help me disable one submit when is focused?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
    $(document).keypress(function(event){
       if (event.which == 13){
           $("#buttonNext").click();
           event.preventDefault();
        }
    });
});
```

It will not trigger twice.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#buttonNext").addEventListener('keypress', e => {
  e.stopPropagation()
})
```

might do the trick. It prevents the event from propagating up in the hierarchy when a *keypress* event happens on the button.